# File_get_contents, PHP, MySQL Insert Issue

Tags: php, mysql, json, file-get-contents

I am attempting to fetch information from a website in JSON format, then import it in to specified tables. So far, I have managed to decrypt the JSON in to a manageable format. From there, I have attempted to insert this data in to an array and then import it to the specified tables as desired. I am truly lost. All information I have used to build this script I found on Stackoverflow and I am extremely grateful for all of your help.

```
**USER.PHP**
<?php
    $user = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/sean.wichers');
    $json = json_decode($user, true);
    {
        $uinfo = array(
            'id' => $json->$id,
            'name' => $json->$name,
            'first_name' => $json->$first_name,
            'last_name' => $json->$last_name,
            'link' => $json->$link,
            'username' => $json->$username,
            'gender' => $json->$gender,
            'locale' => $json->$locale
        );
    }
    include 'user1.php';
?>
```

**USER1.PHP**

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","s*ic*ers_t*g*","******");
    if (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("*wi*he*_***", $con);

    $sql="INSERT INTO jos_users (id, name, username, usertype, block, sendEmail, gid)
          VALUES ('$id', '$name', '$username', 'Registered', 0, 1, 18)"
    mysql_close($con);

    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)) {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo "1 record added... BOOM BABY!!!";
?>
```

Comment: for the first snippet you could simply use, `$uinfo = (array) $json`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! However, after making that change I am given:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in /home/swichers/tagn.it/adduser/1/user.php on line 6

You can see this at http://tagn.it/adduser/1/user.php

Comment: Did you add a semicolon? `$uinfo = (array)$json;`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a semi-colon after your SQL statement, too!

**This (old):**

```
 $sql="INSERT INTO jos_users (id, name, username, usertype, block, sendEmail, gid)
VALUES ('$id', '$name', '$username', 'Registered', 0, 1, 18)"
```

**Should Be:**

```
$sql="INSERT INTO jos_users (id, name, username, usertype, block, sendEmail, gid)
VALUES ('$id', '$name', '$username', 'Registered', 0, 1, 18)";
```

Notice the semi-colon `;` after `18)"`

Also, you are not assigning the $json properties correctly:

**For example:**

```
'id' => $json->$id,
'name' => $json->$name,
```

**Should Be:**

```
'id' => $json->id,
'name' => $json->name,
```

Comment: I have made all of these changes, however I am still receiving, "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in /home/swichers/tagn.it/adduser/1/user.php on line 6".  Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Send me the FULL code you are using in a pastebin link - I will correct the error and send it back to you.

Comment: Here is the FULL code Evan:
user.php
http://pastebin.com/HcFBPWkM
user1.php
http://pastebin.com/SKj1sDRG

Thanks!

Comment: After reading this page over, I realized that you should just be using this code here:
http://pastie.org/3682177

Originally posted by the user below me.

Comment: That code is currently uploaded. You can see he result at:

http://tagn.it/adduser/1/new/user.php

The result is the same.
Thanks

Comment: I get "1 record added... BOOM BABY!!!"

so , you should now be accepting an answer!

Comment: @user1262407 you are not using code http://pastie.org/3682166 that's why the problem. Every time, I told you to use this code, you just used another. From the php error it's clear that your file has at least 60 lines. But when we told you to show FULL code, you are just showing about 20  lines of code. Your problem can not be solved. No one can.